# File upload fails when generating signed apk but when app is in debug files are getting uploaded to server

Tags: android, firebase

I was trying to upload images to server using post and everything is working fine even files are also getting uploaded to server in debug mode but when i am try to upload files when i release app then i was getting as fails can any one help me out

Upload working fine when I’m run app in debug and not able to upload when signed apk is released.

This is for Image picker

```
                intent1.putExtra(IS_NEED_CAMERA, true);
                intent1.putExtra(Constant.MAX_NUMBER, 1);
                intent1.putExtra(IS_NEED_FOLDER_LIST, true);
                startActivityForResult(intent1, Constant.REQUEST_CODE_PICK_IMAGE);
```

onresult

```
case Constant.REQUEST_CODE_PICK_IMAGE:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    ArrayList<ImageFile> list = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Constant.RESULT_PICK_IMAGE);
                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                    for (ImageFile file : list) {
                        String path = file.getPath();
                        builder.append(path + "\n");
                        pdfFileName = path;
                        Log.e("strrrrrr",""+path);
                    }
                    uploadImage();
                }
                break
```

Uploading file

```
private void uploadImage() {
        if (pdfFileName == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "please select an image ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        } else {
            showProgress("Uploading media ...");
            Map<String, RequestBody> map = new HashMap<>();
            File file = new File(pdfFileName);
            TypedFile typedFile = new TypedFile("multipart/form-data", file);
            restClient.getService().upload(typedFile, new Callback<retrofit.client.Response>() {
                @Override
                public void success(retrofit.client.Response response, retrofit.client.Response response2) {
                    sendLinkToServer(filenames, pdfFileName);
                    Log.e("Upload", "success");
                    hideProgress();
                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(UploadFiles.this, "Upload failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.e("Upload", error.getMessage());
                    hideProgress();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: What errors are you getting in logcat?

Comment: there is no error only getting Upload failed

Comment: You can temporarily set the android:debuggable=true flag on your signed release build to find the errors. Also, is the release build using Proguard?

Comment: @divya vatti: Is `Log.e("Upload", error.getMessage());` printing the same message as the Toast on the line above it?

Comment: ya we are using proguard

Comment: In log i got this

Comment: Which action used on intent1 ? Please adapt your code.

Comment: You use some strange image picker without informing us about it.

Comment: You are uploading only the last file picked by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you

make sure into your project level gradle **minifyEnabled** is **false** because in some cases server task not working when it is **true**

```
release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
```